# Mouse follow pattern

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to create an application that will make the mouse follow a certain pattern. One idea is to load a bitmap like

[image]

for example, then make the mouse follow that line.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Currently I'm playing around with

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Usage example to move mouse 5px down

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 5, 0, 0);
```

Which will work fine for my purpose, but I would really like to make it follow a pattern.

If anyone has ANY ideas at all that might help/improve what I'm looking for, I would be so, so thankful!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see the image but perhaps you could use [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx). Also consider [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm), it's created specifically for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Laoujin i.imgur (DOT) com/6UvblKY.png -- try now.
Also, thanks I will take a look what that is. 
I have used Autohotkey before but I'm making a switch from that to C# app to make it more advanced for my purposes :)

Comment: So what is your question? Is it about image recognition, storing a path, calling the method to move the mouse? What exactly are you looking for in answers?

Comment: @CodeCaster If I load a bitmap like this: http://i.imgur.com/04KYbOW.png I want the mouse to follow that specific line. My question was how to do that. I know how to move the mouse, but I don't know how to make it follow that specific line.

Comment: I understand that, but solving your entire problem is too broad for SO. I tried to point out in my comment that you can try to solve each sub-problem and ask specific questions on parts where you get stuck.

Comment: Where is your pattern? Is it in a control? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well I just needed to get pointed towards the right direction so I know where to begin, that's why I made this topic :)

Comment: I gave you a few pointers in my comment. Try AForge for image recognition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few commonly used pathfinding algorithms:

Dijkstra's algorithm and A* are both quite popular.

Dijkstra's algorithm is a good choice for tile-based solutions, which is very fast.  (You could treat each pixel as a tile.)

If you want something simple, try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding#Sample_algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm and [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm]